# Rails fields_for ignores :disabled field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, disabled-input

I'm using Rails 4.1.4 and have the basic structure for nested attributes using fields_for. I've noticed that **disabled** option is totally ignored for the fields inside the fields_for block.

In my code example the first text_field is disabled and the one after fields_for is not. What am I missing here?

```
   ...    
    <%= f.text_field :response_given, disabled: true %>
    <%= f.fields_for :meta_set do |mf| %>
      <%= mf.text_field :name, disabled: true %>
      ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `readonly: true` instead of disabled.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also noticed that readonly: option works but it's not the functionality I need. 

First, I don't want those fields to be sent at all with the form, hence the disabled-tag. Second, I prefer disabled "look" for the select-tags. If you are using readonly for select, it really does not change the functionality.

If you are using disabled for select, user can't even change the select value (which is preferred).

Comment: @hade, did you figure something out?

Comment: @SteveO7, I did not figure this out. I just used readonly-tag, which is far from what I need. I'm guessing this is a bug (or a feature) in Rails 4.1.x version for not disabling nested elements.

Comment: disabled: true ended up working for me, but I'm using simple_form.  It displays the field read only and does not send it with the form.